# C#: Is it possible to save Bitmap to GIF and JPEG without lossy compression?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to save a Bitmap object with all the pixels to GIF and JPEG formats, but without loosing quality at all, so the Bitmap could be loaded back from GIF and JPEG and processed again. I believe that both GIF and JPEG can be encoded without lossy compression, but is it possible to do with .NET? If so how can I do it?

Comment: Well, JPEG in itself is by definion a lossy compression. However there is e.g. JPEG2000 to achieve this (which does not have anything in common with JPG-compression). However your quesdtion is by far too broad for Stack.

Comment: @HimBromBeere JPEG2000 isn't lossless format, just it keeps more details than JPEG.

Comment: [Lossless JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG).

Comment: Lossless JPG exists, but .NET has no native support for it. GIF itself is lossless -- lossy pre-processing to reduce the size may happen in another step, but it does not reduce any quality on its own. When it comes to lossless compression, PNG is generally a better choice than GIF.

Answer (score 1):

No, GIF and JPEG loose information by their respective file format definition and it isn't .NET dependent. You may use some lossless file format that still uses compression like PNG.

Comment: Except for [Lossless JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG).